# C# MS Charting Library RelativeStrengthIndex RSI

Tags: c#, mschart

I am trying to calculate RelativeStrengthIndex RSI using Microsoft Charting library. But I am unable to understand how to actually calculate RSI. In the official documentation, it says Close price as input, UpperBand, Lower band as last parameter. My RSI is wrong. Here is my code.

I am calculating 10 period RSI for close price.

**`This is to calculate Bollinger band using TA-lib library`**

```
 double[] input = _stockData.Select("Convert.ToDouble(Close)", null).Cast<double>().Reverse().Take(40).ToArray();
            int startIdx = 0;
            int endIdx = input.Length - 1;
            int outBegIdx = 0;
            int outNBElement = 0;
            double[] output = new double[input.Length];
            double[] realUpperBand = new double[input.Length];
            double[] realMiddleBand = new double[input.Length];
            double[] realLowerBand = new double[input.Length];
            TaLib.Bbands(startIdx, endIdx, input, period * 2, upperDeviation, lowerDeviation, TaLib.MAType.Ema, out outBegIdx, out outNBElement, realUpperBand, realMiddleBand, realLowerBand);

            realUpperBand = realUpperBand.Where(e => e != default(double)).Select(e => e).ToArray();
            realMiddleBand = realMiddleBand.Where(e => e != default(double)).Select(e => e).ToArray();
            realLowerBand = realLowerBand.Where(e => e != default(double)).Select(e => e).ToArray();
```

**`THis is where Ia m using MS charting library to calculate RSI`**

```
        var chart = new Chart();
        chart.Series.Add("Series1");
        chart.Series.Add("Series2");
        chart.Series.Add("Series3");
        chart.Series.Add("Series4");
        var xvals = new double[21];
        for (int i = 0; i < xvals.Length; i++)
        {
            xvals[i] = 1 * i;
        }
        chart.Series["Series1"].Points.DataBindY(input.Take(21).ToArray());
        chart.Series["Series3"].Points.DataBindY(realUpperBand);
        chart.Series["Series4"].Points.DataBindY(realLowerBand);


        chart.DataManipulator.FinancialFormula(FinancialFormula.RelativeStrengthIndex, "10,2", "Series1", "Series2,Series3,Series4");


        foreach (var item in chart.Series["Series2"].Points)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}::{1}", item.XValue, item.YValues[0]));
        }
```

My resultant 10 values are these as I am using 10 period. These values are wrong.

```
67.8321678321678
48.6230583575715
44.8883076981673
25.6904113625767
24.5922535440154
19.5463410734941
19.2588576538431
16.4244652418174
30.2733037135866
22.7200114375465
52.3084521817947
```

What should I do to get correct values for RSI 10 period.

For example If we try to calculate RSI(3, close) these are the data points.

```
These data points are from 10/26/2016 to 10/21/2016 for stock symbol AAPL
115.59,118.25,117.65,116.6
```

The RSI should be

```
24.5075 for 10/26/2016
```

also for correct result visit this website.
https://www.tradingview.com/chart/OqPrDeTV/

Comment: It might help to have the actual input data and also the expected outcome.

Comment: I have edited my question.